# Why is this while loop giving me an error scala

Tags: scala

Trying to take a list of strings and add them all together to form one string in scala recursively. I don't know why, but my IDE keeps giving me a redline under the while part of my while loop and it says type mismatch, String required. But I've tested it and having the system evaluate (List()==Nil) is valid so whats wrong with the loop?

```
  def concatAlL (l: List[String]) : String =  {
  while (l!=Nil){
     return l.head++concatAlL(l.tail)
  }
  return ""
}
```

Comment: The snippet compiles, so maybe it's an IDE problem. Try a clean build?

Comment: Ugh, I'm having a lot of trouble with eclipse, whenever I try and run something and it has errors, it just outputs whatever it outputted the last time I ran anything, and doesn't say what the error are or anything. Any tips?

Comment: Use Intellij with the Scala plugin. It's awesome.

Comment: You could replace the `l!=Nil` with `!l.isEmpty` and avoid comparisons altogether. You could also use a match expression on the list and both check for empty lists and destructure the head and tail. And you should get rid of all the `return` keywords.

Comment: A [more canonical version](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ec2b8ec18d60c8d1d88).

Comment: Check your imports, you are most likely referencing java.util.List, or something simmilar